# Uncaught error from thread [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-82689] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled

Tags: java, playframework, akka

We got following error, and application get shutdown after some time.

> 2018-08-22 00:38:37 +0530 - [WARN] - from
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool in HikariPool-1 housekeeper 
>   HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper
>   delta=46s982ms745µs775ns).
>
> 2018-08-22 00:38:50 +0530 - [INFO] - from application in
>   application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-82665  Invoices(Duplicate
>   copy) found in report folder: 1219349_Duplicate_Tue Aug 21 13:28:59
>   IST 2018.pdf for order: 1219349
>
> 2018-08-22 00:38:50 +0530 - [INFO] - from application in
>   application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-82665  Customer Invoice
>   Processed for order Number: 1219349 and file path is:
>   /home/decathlon/Play_app_Decashop/d3s/d3s/app/reports/1219349_Duplicate_Tue
>   Aug 21 13:28:59 IST 2018.pdf
>
> 2018-08-22 00:38:50 +0530 - [INFO] - from application in
>   application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-82665  Customer Invoice
>   process duration Time is:2 minutes for Order Number: 1219349
>
> 2018-08-22 00:38:50 +0530 - [ERROR] - from
>   play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler in
>   application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-82665  Exception caught in
>   channelRead future java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException:
>   event executor terminated     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.reject(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:805)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.offerTask(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:345)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.addTask(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:338)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.execute(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:748)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.read(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:689)
>     at
>   play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$channelRead$2$$anonfun$8.apply(PlayRequestHandler.scala:172)
>     at
>   play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$channelRead$2$$anonfun$8.apply(PlayRequestHandler.scala:168)
>     at scala.util.Success$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Try.scala:237)   at
>   scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)  at
>   scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:237)     at
>   scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:237)    at
>   scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:237)    at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)  at
>   play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.executeScheduled(Execution.scala:109)
>     at
>   play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:71)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.link(Promise.scala:304)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.linkRootOf(Promise.scala:289)
>     at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:255)
>     at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:251)
>     at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)     at
>   akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
>     at
>   akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
>     at
>   akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
>     at
>   akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
>     at
>   akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:90)
>     at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:39)    at
>   akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:415)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
>
> 2018-08-22 00:38:50 +0530 - [ERROR] - from
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.rejectedExecution in
>   application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-82665  Failed to submit a
>   listener notification task. Event loop shut down?
>   java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: event executor
>   terminated    at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.reject(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:805)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.offerTask(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:345)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.addTask(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:338)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.execute(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:748)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.safeExecute(DefaultPromise.java:767)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:435)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure(DefaultPromise.java:120)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.setFailure(DefaultChannelPromise.java:87)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.safeExecute(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1004)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:829)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:728)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:709)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.write(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1002)
>     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.write(AbstractChannel.java:246)
>     at
>   play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler.play$core$server$netty$PlayRequestHandler$$sendSimpleErrorResponse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:291)
>     at
>   play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$channelRead$2$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:180)
>     at
>   play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$channelRead$2$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:177)
>     at
>   scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
>     at scala.util.Failure$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Try.scala:216)   at
>   scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)  at
>   scala.util.Failure.recover(Try.scala:216)     at
>   scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Future.scala:326)    at
>   scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Future.scala:326)    at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)  at
>   play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.executeScheduled(Execution.scala:109)
>     at
>   play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:71)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.link(Promise.scala:304)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.linkRootOf(Promise.scala:289)
>     at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:255)
>     at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:251)
>     at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)     at
>   akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
>     at
>   akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
>     at
>   akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
>     at
>   akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
>     at
>   akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:90)
>     at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:39)    at
>   akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:415)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
>
> 2018-08-22 00:38:55 +0530 - [ERROR] - from akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl
>   in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-82665  Uncaught error
>   from thread [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-82689] shutting
>   down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled
>
> 2018-08-22 00:38:55 +0530 - [INFO] - from application in
>   application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-82665  Customer Invoice
>   Processing for order Number: 1219349
>
> 2018-08-22 00:40:02 +0530 - [INFO] - from application in
>   DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4  scheduler is running for import order
>
> 2018-08-22 00:40:02 +0530 - [INFO] - from application in
>   DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4  Going for sftp connection.
>
> 2018-08-22 00:40:12 +0530 - [INFO] - from application in
>   DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4  is connection established :true
>
> 2018-08-22 00:40:22 +0530 - [INFO] - from
>   service.DecashopOrderImporter in DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4

Comment: What's your setup? You're using Play! Framework, but what else? How are you calling your logic and what's your exception handling like? Show the essential code path to your problem.

Comment: I am using Play Framework version 2.5, We have 3 scheduler processes running at the same time, And at some point of time there were multiple request for report generation, due to which there were exceptions. But I am not sure these exceptions are due to over load or there is any error causing these exceptions.